# How do I connect to an FTP website hosted on Unix server through SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I need to copy a file from a folder location to Unix server. I am trying to use FTP task in SSIS but while testing the connection from FTP task to the Unix server, I get the below error message:

#### Error message:

```
Connection could not be established, Server Name, Port number or 
credentials might be invalid.
```

I have used the following credentials

```
Server Name: mohawk.am.lilly.com
port number: 22
```

I provided a valid user name and password. When I tested the connection, I get the error message.

Could someone point to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Port number **`22`** is associated with *`Secure FTP (SFTP)`*. You need to use port **`21`** to connect to *`FTP`*, if that is what you are trying to do.

*`FTP Task`* in SSIS is not capable to perform Secure FTP (SFTP) operations. Read more about other options to perform SFTP within SSIS in this MSDN forums answer:

[*Can SSIS do SFTP? and how?*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/00043b62-d243-427a-8118-3b40e9281050/)